# Loading fixed width html into responsive <iframe>

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design, fixed-width

I have an webpage with faulty responsive design, that I am trying to load into my `<iframe>`. That page is completely broken below certain width (key parts missing). Unfortunately, I have no control over that particular web page design.

On my side, I am using <iframe> with responsive design as follow:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <iframe src="faulty_page.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper iframe {
  width: 1000px;   /* The loaded page is brogen below width of 1000px */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  --scale: calc(100vw / 1000px);  /* This is invalid */
  transfrom: scale(var(--scale));
}
```

The problem is, that CSS `calc()` function does require the argument after division to be a number and not width, making the expression `calc(100vw / 1000px);` invalid.

Is there a way to load a fixed width page into responsive design `<iframe>`? I know, that I can use JavaScript to work around the limitation of CSS `calc()`, but I would like to stick to pure HTML/CSS if possible.

An ugly workaround might be to use @media to get the idea how many pixels is 100vw and gradually change the value of --scale variable.

```
@media only (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 999px){ --scale: 0.95}
@media only (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 949px){ --scale: 0.90}
@media only (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 899px){ --scale: 0.85}
etc...
```

But that is a solution I am also trying to avoid